# Inverse Laplace transform not obtained

Tags: special-functions, inverse, integral-transforms

I can't seem to be able to compute the inverse Laplace transform of a Laplace transform:

```
LaplaceTransform[x *  Sqrt[l^2 - x^2], x, s]

Out[27]= -(1/(32 π))
 Sqrt[-(1/l^2)] l^4 (l^2)^(3/2)
   s^3 MeijerG[{{-(3/2)}, {}}, {{-3, -(3/2), -1}, {}}, -(1/16)
      l^4 s^4 Sign[Im[Log[-(1/l^2)]]], 2] Sign[Im[Log[-(1/l^2)]]]
```

But if I try to do the reverse:

```
InverseLaplaceTransform[-(1/(32 π)) Sqrt[-(1/l^2)]
   l^4 (l^2)^(3/2)
   s^3 MeijerG[{{-(3/2)}, {}}, {{-3, -(3/2), -1}, {}}, -(1/16)
      l^4 s^4 Sign[Im[Log[-(1/l^2)]]], 2] Sign[
   Im[Log[-(1/l^2)]]], s, x]

Out[29]= -(1/(32 π))
 Sqrt[-(1/l^2)] l^4 (l^2)^(3/2)
   InverseLaplaceTransform[
   s^3 MeijerG[{{-(3/2)}, {}}, {{-3, -(3/2), -1}, {}}, -(1/16)
        l^4 s^4 Sign[Im[Log[-(1/l^2)]]], 2], s, x] Sign[
   Im[Log[-(1/l^2)]]]
```

Shouldn't this evaluate to the original? As to why I'd want to do this: I am trying to solve an equation using Laplace transforms.

Comment: Things like this actually happen far more frequently than you'd expect: operation so-and-so is easy to do, but the inverse is not too easy...

Comment: I agree, but is there an alternative to Laplace transforms for solving complicated equations?

Comment: @J.M. Like marriage ...

Comment: @highBandWidth What are those equations?

Comment: There are many alternatives. But it depends on what you are trying to solve. Are you trying to Solve a differential equation? If so, try using DSolve. If that does not work, you may be able to get a numerical solution using NDSolve.

Comment: Well, I have an integral equation, specifically a Volterra equation like $y(x) = f(x) + \int_0^{x+a}y(t)K(t-x) dt$ where I have to solve for $y$. The answer needs InverseLaplace[Laplace[K]/(1-Laplace[K])].

Comment: @belisarius ... or a lobotomy. :-p

Comment: @highBandWidth Can't use use recursion on $y(x)$ (and end up with a series of integrals on $K$) ?

Comment: 1. Convert it to a differential equation if possible.

2. If you cannot get a symbolic solution for the Laplace transform, then try getting a numerical solution. Write out the integral transform for a Laplace transform and try to apply it numerically to your equations using NIntegrate.

Comment: Using `Assumptions` can help sometimes. Putting here `Assumptions -> l > 0` gives the answer via other special functions. But still it doesn't find inverse. Also one can try some special cases. Here it wouldn't do even for $l=1$, so...